# Calculating in consecutive dates in DataFrames with multiple key values avoiding loops with Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I´be been working in a stock analysis using pandas and I´m regarding a quite tricky concept called "actual cover" which is a concept that only makes sense in a ad-hoc analysis since "actual cover" means the measure (in days) of how much the current stock position would last, assuming that there would not be any restocking from that point on.

Ex:

```
TIMESTAMP   MATERIAL_GOODS  STOCK_POS   SALES
2017-03-29  PRODUCT A       47          2
2017-03-30  PRODUCT A       43          4
2017-03-31  PRODUCT A       38          5
2017-04-01  PRODUCT A       49          11
2017-04-02  PRODUCT A       49          0
2017-04-03  PRODUCT A       45          4
2017-04-04  PRODUCT A       38          7
2017-04-05  PRODUCT A       30          8
2017-04-06  PRODUCT A       44          6
2017-04-07  PRODUCT A       36          8   
2017-04-08  PRODUCT A       47          10  
2017-04-09  PRODUCT A       46          1   
2017-04-11  PRODUCT A       31          8   
2017-04-10  PRODUCT A       39          7
```

I´ve come up with this solution (which is working...)

```
actual_cover = []

for i in DF.index:
    z = 1
    counter = 0
    rest = DF['STOCK_POS'].iloc[i]
    while (rest >= 0)&(i+z < DF.index.max()):
        rest -= DF['SALES'].iloc[i+z]
        counter += 1
        z += 1    

    actual_cover.append(counter)
    print('Progress: {}%'.format(round((i/len(DF.index))*100,2)), end="\r", flush=True)
```

Here is the output for the example and actually how it should look like:

```
TIMESTAMP   MATERIAL_GOODS  STOCK_POS   SALES   ACTUAL_COVER(days)
2017-03-29  PRODUCT A       47          2       9
2017-03-30  PRODUCT A       43          4       8 
2017-03-31  PRODUCT A       38          5       7
2017-04-01  PRODUCT A       49          11      9
2017-04-02  PRODUCT A       49          0       8
2017-04-03  PRODUCT A       45          4       7
2017-04-04  PRODUCT A       38          7       6
2017-04-05  PRODUCT A       30          8       5
2017-04-06  PRODUCT A       44          6       7
2017-04-07  PRODUCT A       36          8       6
2017-04-08  PRODUCT A       47          10      12
2017-04-09  PRODUCT A       46          1       11
2017-04-11  PRODUCT A       31          8       8
2017-04-10  PRODUCT A       39          7       10
```

But with this code, it takes about 1 sec to calculate the actual cover of one item at one store. Since I need to do this calculation for about 40k itens at 2k stores, is not exactly a practical solution.

I´ve try to work something with rolling and other pandas tools but unable to get the calculations right.

**My question is: there are a more "Pythonic", fast, efficient way to do the same calculation?**

**EDIT**

So..@Haleemur Ali actually gave a pretty good clue of the problem since:

```
def actual_cover(rownum, frame):
    mask = frame.SALES[rownum+1:].cumsum() > frame.STOCK_POS[rownum]
    not_covered = np.where(mask.values)[0]
    return np.nan if not_covered.size == 0 else not_covered[0]+1
```

Works properly if you have a `DataFrame` with just one item and just one store, but my original problem looks more like this:

```
TIMESTAMP   ITEM        STORE   STOCK_POS       SALES   
2017-01-01  4251695     1216    0.0             0.0         
2017-01-01  4251695     1269    1.0             0.0         
2017-01-01  4264750     1269    0.0             0.0         
2017-01-01  4264750     L101    0.0             0.0         
2017-01-01  4252056     L836    308.0           0.0         
2017-01-01  4252056     L856    158.0           1.0         
2017-01-01  4255732     L101    360.0           0.0         
2017-01-01  4255732     L110    101.0           0.0         
2017-01-01  4262145     L715    8.0             0.0         
2017-01-01  4262145     L794    0.0             0.0
```

When I applied the `actual_cover` function with one item(4252056), one store(1001), filtering the DataFrame like this:

```
DF = DF[(DF['ITEM'] == 4252056)&(DF['STORE'] == '1001')]
DF.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
DF['ACTUAL_COVER'] = DF.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, DF), axis=1)
```

I got that result:

```
TIMESTAMP   ITEM        STORE   STOCK_POS       SALES    ACTUAL_COVER
2017-01-01  4252056     1001    551             0        35.0
2017-01-02  4252056     1001    531             20       34.0
2017-01-03  4252056     1001    514             17       33.0
2017-01-04  4252056     1001    1146            28       64.0
2017-01-05  4252056     1001    1130            16       63.0
2017-01-06  4252056     1001    1865            15       76.0
2017-01-07  4252056     1001    1843            22       75.0
2017-01-08  4252056     1001    1833            10       74.0
2017-01-09  4252056     1001    1814            19       73.0
2017-01-10  4252056     1001    1808            6        72.0
```

Which its perfect. But since I have numerous stores (1300) that work like keys, I need a `groupby` kind of solution.

Using the current function:

```
def actual_cover_grouped(grp):
    return grp.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, grp), axis=1)
```

Like this (processing time about 50 min):

```
group_item_store = DF.groupby(by=[DF['ITEM'], DF['STORE']])
DF['ACTUAL_COVER'] = group_item_store.apply(actual_cover_grouped
                                            ).values.flatten()
```

That is the result for the same segment (item-4252056 / store-1001):

```
TIMESTAMP   ITEM        STORE   STOCK_POS       SALES    ACTUAL_COVER
    2017-01-01  4252056     1001    551             0        NaN
    2017-01-02  4252056     1001    531             20       NaN
    2017-01-03  4252056     1001    514             17       NaN
    2017-01-04  4252056     1001    1146            28       NaN
    2017-01-05  4252056     1001    1130            16       NaN
    2017-01-06  4252056     1001    1865            15       NaN
    2017-01-07  4252056     1001    1843            22       NaN
    2017-01-08  4252056     1001    1833            10       NaN
    2017-01-09  4252056     1001    1814            19       NaN
    2017-01-10  4252056     1001    1808            6        NaN
```

**Why is the grouped version not working?**

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to include input data and what you'd need the output to look like. And please refrain from posting code and data as images, post it as text. Also keep it simple, with sensible names for your variables and a description of the calculation you want to perform. You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done! Thanks for the headsup

Comment: Sorry, what is `ACTUAL_COVER`?

Comment: I describe all the variables in text man....¬¬

"actual cover" means the measure (in days) of how much the current stock position would last, assuming that there would not be any restocking from that point on..."

Comment: looking at your data it seems that you have some restocking going on, its just not represented in its own column, is that correct?

Comment: @HaleemurAli correct.

But that´s not exactly relevant since both "cover" and "actual cover" are positional measures.

Is a way of evaluate the level of stock in terms of days.

The normal behavior is a decreasing cover that returns from time to time to a target position.

Comment: How do you get `actual cover = 10` for the date `2017-04-10`? is it using sales data from dates not shown in this sample?

Comment: @HaleemurAli yes. This is just a sample.

The actual DataFrame has 365 rows, one for each day of the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first optimization to this type of code is to replace looping with native numpy / pandas functions and using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

using the definition for actual cover as

> the measure (in days) of how much the current stock position would last

one can equivalently say, that the actual cover is

```
the first day such that the cumulative sum of sales for all following days exceeds 
the stock position on a given day
```

using this definition of actual cover the following function returns the actual_cover given a row number

```
def actual_cover(rownum, frame):
    mask = frame.SALES[rownum+1:].cumsum() > frame.STOCK_POS[rownum]
    not_covered = np.where(mask.values)[0]
    return np.nan if not_covered.size == 0 else not_covered[0]+1
```

Then, you can apply it to the dataframe and assign the values to a new column

```
df['ACTUAL_COVER(days)'] = df.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, df), axis=1)
```

notes:

i used the name `df` instead of `DF`, so you have to change that when you try this code on your dataset

the function uses row index values to determine the number of days. So, for the function to work correctly, there must be a row for each day, even if no sales occur on that day, and the rows must be ordered by the timestamp

the function applied to the dataframe snippet above will return `np.nan` for the rows where the cumulative sum never exceeds the stock position, i.e. it outputs the following:

```
df.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, df), axis=1)
# output
0     9.0
1     8.0
2     7.0
3     9.0
4     8.0
5     7.0
6     6.0
7     5.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    NaN
13    NaN
```

*this differs from the sample output you provide because you have truncated rows from the whole dataset in the example*

The `actual_cover` function may be applied in a grouped dataframe, but requires further massaging

```
def actual_cover_grouped(grp):
    return grp.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, grp), axis=1)

grouped = df.groupby('MATERIAL_GOODS')

df['Actual Cover'] = grouped.apply(actual_cover_grouped).values.flatten()
```

Comment: can you share long it took to calculate over your whole data set

Comment: That´s great, but one issue though...

When I tried to apply the grouped DataFrame function, i got the followed message error:

'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'

To answer your question, I selected  1 item 1 store randomly and the time of execution was:

original code: 13.15 sec
native numpy code: 0.26 sec

I´m still running the code for the whole dataset and will post the results later.

Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: there was a typo in my code in the last line, which I corrected following your comment. `df['Actual Cover'] = grouped.apply(actual_cover_grouped).values.flatten()`

Comment: I´ve edited the question instead of putting the issues regarding the "grouped" solution here, so I could explain the details and also so people can follow the development of the question.

Comment: I´ve edited the title to be more generic since the center of the problem is not the concept of "Actual Cover"  but calculate in a consecutive manner for dataframes with multiple key (categorical) values

Answer (score 0):

I´m not fully satisfed, but I was able to transform 3 loops in just one with the following code:

```
aux_dict = {}
counter = 0
begin = time.time()
for name, group in grouped_cob:
    AUX_DF = group.copy()
    AUX_DF.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    AUX_DF["ACTUAL_COVER"] = AUX_DF.apply(lambda x: actual_cover(x.name, AUX_DF), axis=1)
    aux_dict.update({name: AUX_DF})

    final = time.time()
    counter +=1
    print('Progress: {}%'.format(round((counter/len(grouped_cob))*100,2)) + 
          ' Parcial processing time: '+str(final-inicio), end="\r", flush=True)


TESTE = pd.concat(aux_dict)
```

and the calculations are correct.